# How to know processing times for Consular processing?

Tags: usa, immigration, greencard

I am filing for my parent's Greencard while they are in the United States. I used the website https://egov.uscis.gov/processing-times/ to see how long does it take to go AOS route and it sounds like it takes more than a year for that. However, there is no authoritative uscis source that tells me how long does it take to finish `Consular processing`.

I found some sources like https://citizenpath.com/green-card-consular-processing/ which say that it takes 4-12 months to do consular processing but still this is not coming from USCIS.

My question is that is there a USCIS source that can tell me how long does it take for consular processing to finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filing for an IR-1 visa for a relative living abroad involves 3 government agencies: USCIS, NVC and Consulate.

1) For USCIS processing times for the I-130, please use the link that you provided: https://egov.uscis.gov/processing-times/

2) The NVC does not have a structured table like USCIS, the best that they have is this website: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/immigrate/nvc-timeframes.html

It will only give you an idea of which applications they're working on right now.

3) For consulates there's no website to consult and timelines vary widely. Ranging from a few weeks to over a year. There are websites/discussion boards that users share their own timeline and that way you can have an ideia of how long its taking.

For the consulate in Mumbai, India, for example, it seems to be taking 3-4 months to schedule an interview.